Finding an iptables extension to match IP based on the current IP of an interface
Question
I am trying to configure DNAT for my virtual machines (VMs), but it is challenging because the public IP address of my host machine (Host) is assigned by DHCP and changes dynamically. I'm looking for an iptables extension that can match the source/destination IP based on the current IP of a given interface. This would make it easier to compose my DNAT rules. If you know of such an extension or a better solution, please share.
Network topology:
net topology

I did not have enough reputation to post images so I left a link here


Host's public IP (e.g., 1.1.1.1) changes over time
Host connects to the Internet via enp0. Other interfaces also provide Internet access but without public IPs.
Host sets up virbr0 for private networking with VMs, with static, manually assigned IPs.
A VM in the private network (e.g. 192.168.122.154) serves a UDP service on port 4567.
iptables rules must ensure access to 192.168.122.154:4567

What I'm Looking For:
An iptables extension that allows me to change my rule from this:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \
    -d 1.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

to this:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \
    -m magic-extension --dst enp0 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

where -m magic-extension --dst enp0 means match IP packages whose destination IP is one of the current IPs of the interface enp0.
What I know
I know this can be done using ipset with a cron job to update the IP set, but I'm looking for a more compact solution.
Details
My scenario have these requirements:

DNAT packages from Internet targeting 1.1.1.1:4567 to VM:4567. This is the original meaning of DNAT.
DNAT packages from the Host targeting 1.1.1.1:4567 to VM:4567, allowing access to the service from Host via a domain. For example, DDNS service is adopted to record the latest public IP of Host with domain Host. Someone, operating on Host, tries to access the VM service by the network location Host:4567, which is resolved as 1.1.1.1:4567.
Route packages from VM  targeting 1.1.1.1:4567 to VM:4567. Same as the previous requirement, allow access to Host:4567 from VMs.

With only the first requirement, I could avoid the explicit use of 1.1.1.1 so changing Host IP is not a problem:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \
    -i enp0 -p udp --dport 4567 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

iptables -t filter -I FORWARD \
    -i enp0 -p udp -d 192.168.122.154 --dport 4567 \
    -j ACCEPT

The trick is to match the packages based on the interface at which the packages arrive.
But the trick do not apply to the remaining 2 requirements and I must switch to hardencoding an IP and face the problem of dynamic public IP of Host.
Bellows are my current iptables rules:
Requirement I
forward traffic from inet
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \
    -d 1.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

iptables -t filter -I FORWARD \
    -d 1.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j ACCEPT

Requirement II
forward traffic from Host
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT \
    -p udp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 4567 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

Requirement III
forward traffic from VM
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING \
    -s 192.168.122.154 -d 192.168.122.154 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.122.1

This rule seems weird, because I uses SNAT for DNAT. With out SNAT, packages with src_ip = dst_ip = 192.168.122.154 = VM_ip are forwarded to VM but never "received" by the VM. Actually, from logs of VM, I found that the packages are discarded just before the INPUT chain. I only saw them at PREROUTING chain.
I do not know the reason but it is possible to avoid by SNAT the source to 192.168.122.1.
With this magic-extension, I could change my rules to:
# req I
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING \
    -m magic-extension --dst enp0 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD \
    -m magic-extension --dst enp0 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j ACCEPT

# req II
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT \
    -m magic-extension --dst enp0 -p udp --dport 4567 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567

# req III
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING \
    -m magic-extension --dst enp0 -s 192.168.122.154 -p udp --dport 8854 \
    -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.122.1

Another humble question:
For years, I have benefited from the wealth of knowledge shared by the Stack Exchange community, though I am relatively new to contributing questions myself. I recently posted a networking-related question on Stack Overflow, only to realize it was off-topic and subsequently had it closed and deleted. Despite reading through the documentation of ServerFault, I am still uncertain whether my question aligns better here or on Super User.
If this question does not belong here, could someone kindly leave a brief comment to guide me before closing it? I apologize in advance if I'm mistaken again.
Thank you sincerely for your understanding and support.

If the destination IP of the packets will be your enp0 interface, you should control this flow on the INPUT chain. By doing the following, in fact, you would be managing packets whose destination IP is the ip address of port enp0:
iptables -I INPUT -i enp0 -p udp --dport 8854  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.154:4567
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.122.154 -j ACCEPT

